# loop simple calculator: will not loop back to original input

Tags: python, loops, calculator

Simple calculator. Asks the following:

1) Input for number 1

2) Input for number 2

3) What do you want to do, add/subtract/multiple/divide?

If a user has correct input for Question 1, but incorrect input for Questions 2 or 3, it directs them back to Question 1. I would like to know how invalid input for Question 2 can redirect back to Question 2 so the user may try again. If Question 3 receives invalid input, I would like it to redirect back to Question 3 so the user may try again.

```
# Returns the sum of num1 and num2
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

# returns the results of subtracting num1 - num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

# returns the result of multiplying num1 * num2
def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

# returns the result of dividing num1/num2
def div(num1, num2):
    try:
        return num1 / num2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("handled div by zero. Returning zero.")
    return 0

def main():
    validInput = False
    while not validInput:
        try:
            num1 = int(input("What is number 1?"))
            num2 = int(input("What is number 2?"))
            operation = int(input("What do you want to do? 1. add, 2. subtract, 3. multiply, or 4. divide. Enter number:"))
            validInput = True
        except:
            print("invalid input. Try again")
    if (operation == 1):
        print("Adding...")
        print(add(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 2):
        print("Subtracting...")
        print(sub(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 3):
        print("Multiplying...")
        print(mul(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 4):
        print("Dividing...")
        print(div(num1, num2))
    else:
        print("I don't understand")

main()
```

Comment: I think you should only catch `ValueError`. In particular, it will not be possible to exit with a `KeyboardInterrupt` as it will be caught and continue the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop to check for each operation/steps, if valid then proceed if not then just keep looping.

```
def tryUntilSuccess(prompt,range=None):
    while True:
        try:
            result = int(input(prompt))
            if range and result not in range:
                raise Exception
            else:
                return result
        except:
            print("invalid input. Try again")

def main():
    num1 = tryUntilSuccess("What is number 1?")
    num2 = tryUntilSuccess("What is number 2?")
    operation = tryUntilSuccess("What do you want to do? 1. add, 2. subtract, 3. multiply, or 4. divide. Enter number:", [1,2,3,4])

    if (operation == 1):
        print("Adding...")
        print(add(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 2):
        print("Subtracting...")
        print(sub(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 3):
        print("Multiplying...")
        print(mul(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 4):
        print("Dividing...")
        print(div(num1, num2))
    else:
        print("I should not be printed.")
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are a lot of ways of doing this, this is the probably the way that'll be easiest to understand.

Code:

```
# Returns the sum of num1 and num2
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2


# returns the results of subtracting num1 - num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


# returns the result of multiplying num1 * num2
def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2


# returns the result of dividing num1/num2
def div(num1, num2):
    try:
        return num1 / num2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("handled div by zero. Returning zero.")
        return 0

def main():
    validInput = False
    num1,num2,operation = None,None,None
    while not validInput:
        try:
            if num1 is None: num1 = int(input("What is number 1?"))
            if num2 is None: num2 = int(input("What is number 2?"))
            if operation is None: operation = int(input("What do you want to do? 1. add, 2. subtract, 3. multiply, or 4. divide. Enter number:"))
            validInput = True
        except:
            print("invalid input. Try again")
    if (operation == 1):
        print("Adding...")
        print(add(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 2):
        print("Subtracting...")
        print(sub(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 3):
        print("Multiplying...")
        print(mul(num1, num2))
    elif (operation == 4):
        print("Dividing...")
        print(div(num1, num2))
    else:
        print("I don't understand")

main()
```

Comment: We define the answers to the questions we ask the user as num1,num2 and operation before we even ask them. We set those answers to "None". Then for each time before we ask the question, we check to see if the answer is still None, or if it has changed to a suitable value.

Comment: As I stated above, I think you should only catch `ValueError`. In particular, it will not be possible to exit with a `KeyboardInterrupt` as it will be caught and continue the loop.